# Need To Randomize Selections From A List But Ensure Uniqueness

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I'm building a tool to randomize setup for a very large modular card game. There are several lists from which I need to select 2 to 6 non-duplicate entries, and each list is on a separate tab from the main randomizer.

I've been using this formula to get randomized selections:

```
=INDEX(Characters!A1:A, RANDBETWEEN(2,47))
```

This forumla is copied into 5 different cells to randomize 5 different selections. The list is long enough that duplicates don't happen often, but they do happen. I can't find a way to prevent duplicate selections.

If I was doing this in Perl I'd define the list items into an array and then randomly pop out array entries; unfortunately I need this portable across a wide range of devices, not all of which support Perl, which is why I'm using Google Sheets to begin with. I see that there's an array command in Google Sheets but I can't quite parse the syntax. Is the array command the way I want to go? If so, can anyone suggest good resources to grok that? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please read [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en). If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: As Rubén indicates, this type of question has been asked quite often on Stack. I suspect that even minimal research using keywords would turn up a solution without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick 5 random non-blank values from `A1:A` with `sortn()` like this:

```
=sortn( 
  Characters!A1:A, 
  5, 0, 
  sign(len(Characters!A1:A)) 
  * 
  randarray(rows(Characters!A1:A)), 
  false 
)
```

Comment: Hi. The OP's problem is with duplicate values  - _"I can't find a way to prevent duplicate selections."_ This formula doesn't remove possible duplicates from the output. On a tangent, both Rubén and Eric Tyler are suggesting that there are solutions to be found to the OP's question. That may or not be the case, but perhaps it gives pause to ensure that one  ought [Answer well-asked questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP's description of their possible Perl solution suggests that the values in `Characters!A1:A` are unique. They want to avoid showing duplicates in _results_ as they are randomly picked from values. The answer avoids duplicates in _results_, provided there are no duplicates in values.

Comment: "provided there are no duplicates in values" - and this is what I understood was happening sometimes (possibly rarely?). That is , there _are_ duplicates occasionally in the  values.  I may well have it wrong, and this is all moot ;) Presumably the OP will let us know in due course.